# Multiple TPUv2 devices in one training script?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tpu

As part of the Tensorflow Research Cloud initiative, I have access to 100 TPU v2 machines with 8 TPUs on them (TPU v2-8s).

I need to achieve model data parallelism.  Is there a way for me to run data parallelism on the 100 machines at once ? I would rather use `tf.distribute.TPUStrategy` if possible. Or do I absolutely need to write my own script that communicates between the machines to average the gradients between them.

Comment: Do you have access to larger Cloud TPU v2 Pod slices e.g. v2-32, v2-64, ...?
A TPU pod consists of many connected TPU machines and you can train on them as you would do on a single machine using `tf.distribute.TPUStrategy`.
https://cloud.google.com/tpu

Comment: No, otherwise I would use that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, currently we don't have a good way of all-reducing gradients across TPU devices over regular network.